# TEX Quotes UVa Problem 272, Wrong answer and Correct Answer

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, c++11, char

I am referring to this https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=208 problem. The problem is easy and self-explanatory. I made 2 attempts out of which one was Accepted and other was given Wrong Answer verdict.

The code which got selected is below where I did char by char input and output,

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char c;
    int flag = 0;
    while((c = getchar())!=EOF) {
        if(c == '\"') {
            if(flag) {
                cout<<'\''<<'\'';
                flag = 0;
            }
            else {
                cout<<'`'<<'`';
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout<<c;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Whereas as following is the code which got wrong answer, here I took a line as input at a time. To me it does the same thing, but wrong answer.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    int flag = 0, c = 0;
    while(getline(cin, s)) {

        if(c) {cout<<'\n';}     //don't print newline first time
        c=1;

        for(auto& x : s) {
            if(x == '\"') {
                if(flag) {
                    cout<<'\''<<'\'';
                    flag = 0;
                }
                else {
                    cout<<'`'<<'`';
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                cout<<x;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to figure out what's the issue ?
It will be helpful if someone can point out the problem in the second version.

Comment: did you write a test that compares actual and expected output for the two codes?

Comment: yes the diff output does not shows any change

Comment: the thing is that your problem is "some online judge reports: Wrong Answer", that is not something others can reproduce (without creating an account and logging in). You should try to find a test case where output differs, and if you cannot do that, why bother about someone complaining about your code when they cannot tell you what is wrong about it ;)

Comment: more seriously, I actually tried to see a difference for different input, but I couldnt find any. Online judges typically use corner cases to catch subtle bugs. You need to find the corner case that reveals the bug (given there is any), because you cannot fix when you don't know what to fix

Comment: If the input stream ends with `\n`, the first program outputs it, but the second program does not. It only emits `\n` between lines, never at the end of the last line.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks, I think that's where 2nd one is failing.